# drf user serializer return custom data

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've been trying to create a drf app and wanted to achieve a sign in view that does two things:

1. set's the cookies automatically
2. returns the url and the username of the user

the issue is specifically in the validate function inside the serializer code

views.py:

```
class CookieTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get("refresh"):
            # the cookie part works well
            # the part that doesn't is in the serializer below

            user = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
            
            user = user.validate(data=request.data) if user.is_valid()
            response.data["user"] = user.data if user.is_valid() else user.errors
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(style={"input type": "password"}, write_only=True)

    #
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "url",
            "username",
            "password",
        )
        # read_only_fields = ("id")

    def validate(self, data):
        data["username"] = self["username"]
        data["password"] = self["url"]
        return super().validate(data)
```

so as you can see the validate option is trying to get the username and the url data to return it, but instead it's trying to create a new account. so maybe the validate option was not right. I researched on the drf docs but there seem to be an entirely other function called create. so I don't know how validate is not working. maybe I'm supposed to type in another function

Answer (score 0):

In your validate function, you cannot access `self['username']` – you can only access user data through `self.instance`; but, otherwise, you only can access the instance if you passed it to the serializer in a construct like:

```
user_serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data, instance=user_obj)
```

What do you need is after user login, so I recommend to you this post: [Login and Register User Django Rest Framewrok](https://medium.com/django-rest/django-rest-framework-login-and-register-user-fd91cf6029d5); I am pretty sure you can get what you need there.